# Stuck with my SQL update - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I expect someone could help me.

I'm stuck with my table that I try to update

I come from this `#TempTable1`:

```
DATE       NO_CDE   NO_OF   variable1   FLAG    LINE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-23 1        10          0       E       1
2017-05-23 2        20          0       E       1
2017-05-22 1        10          0       E       1
2017-05-22 2        20          0       E       1
2017-05-19 1        10          0       E       1
2017-05-19 2        20          0       E       1
2017-05-18 1        10          0       E       1
2017-05-18 2        20          0       E       1
2017-05-17 1        10          0       E       1
2017-05-17 2        20          0       E       1
2017-05-16 1        10          0       E       1
2017-05-16 2        20          0       E       1
2017-05-15 1        NULL        19      E       1
2017-05-15 2        NULL        13      E       1
2017-05-12 1        NULL        16      E       1
2017-05-12 2        NULL        10      E       1
2017-05-11 1        NULL        15      E       1
2017-05-11 2        NULL        9       E       1
2017-05-10 1        NULL        14      E       1
2017-05-10 2        NULL        8       E       1
```

My desired table `#TempTable1`:

```
DATE       NO_CDE   NO_OF   variable1   FLAG    LINE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-05-23 1        10          19      E       1
2017-05-23 2        20          13      E       1
2017-05-22 1        10          19      E       1
2017-05-22 2        20          13      E       1
2017-05-19 1        10          19      E       1
2017-05-19 2        20          13      E       1
2017-05-18 1        10          19      E       1
2017-05-18 2        20          13      E       1
2017-05-17 1        10          19      E       1
2017-05-17 2        20          13      E       1
2017-05-16 1        10          19      E       1
2017-05-16 2        20          13      E       1
2017-05-15 1        NULL        19      E       1
2017-05-15 2        NULL        13      E       1
2017-05-12 1        NULL        16      E       1
2017-05-12 2        NULL        10      E       1
2017-05-11 1        NULL        15      E       1
2017-05-11 2        NULL        9       E       1
2017-05-10 1        NULL        14      E       1
2017-05-10 2        NULL        8       E       1
```

The cases are :

> If no_OF is not null, get the max from the lines with the same CDE and NO_OF = null
>
> if flag is <> from 'E', get the max from the lines with the same CDE and NO_OF = null
>
> if no_of is null and flag = 'E' then keep the value in variable1

What I tried is :

```
UPDATE #TempTable1
SET variable1 =
CASE 
    WHEN NO_OF IS NULL and FLAG = 'E'
    THEN variable1
    ELSE(   select max(table1.variable1)
            from #TempTable1 table1 
            Left JOIN #TempTable1 table2 
                ON  table1.NO_CDE = table2.NO_CDE 
                AND table1.LINE = table2.LINE
                and table1.NO_OF = table2.NO_OF
            where table1.FLAG = 'E'
            and table1.NO_OF is null
        )
END;
```

here is the DLL to create and insert in table

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable1') is not null
Drop table #TempTable1;

create table #TempTable1 (
    DATE datetime not null,
    NO_CDE int not null,
    NO_OF int,
    variable1 int not null,
    FLAG char not null,
    LINE smallint not null
);

insert into #TempTable1
values (2017-05-23, 1, 10, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-23, 2, 20, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-22, 1, 10, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-22, 2, 20, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-19, 1, 10, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-19, 2, 20, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-18, 1, 10, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-18, 2, 20, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-17, 1, 10, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-17, 2, 20, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-16, 1, 10, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-16, 2, 20, 0, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-15, 1, NULL, 19, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-15, 2, NULL, 13, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-12, 1, NULL, 16, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-12, 2, NULL, 10, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-11, 1, NULL, 15, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-11, 2, NULL, 9, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-10, 1, NULL, 14, 'E', 1),
(2017-05-10, 2, NULL, 8, 'E', 1);
```

Comment: please add some DDL statements for creating tables as well

Comment: What was wrong with what you tried?   Did you get an error?

Comment: When the NO_OF is not Null or if the Flag is not 'E', I got 374 on each row. 374 is the highest value of variable 1 in the hole table

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because your sub query in the update statement does not tie back to the table you specified to update.

[image]

you should rather make use of FROM clause in TSQL's update statement, to join the max value back onto the table you are updating, and specify the table you are updating.

```
UPDATE Base
SET variable1 =
CASE 
    WHEN Base.NO_OF IS NULL and Base.FLAG = 'E'
    THEN variable1
    ELSE MaxVariableForCDE.MaxVariable1
END
FROM
    #TempTable1 as Base
    INNER JOIN (
            select
                table1.NO_CDE,
                table1.FLAG,
                table1.LINE,
                max(table1.variable1) as MaxVariable1
            from #TempTable1 table1 
            where table1.FLAG = 'E'
            and table1.NO_OF is null
            GROUP BY
                table1.NO_CDE,
                table1.FLAG,
                table1.LINE) as MaxVariableForCDE ON
        Base.NO_CDE = MaxVariableForCDE.NO_CDE
    AND Base.FLAG = MaxVariableForCDE.FLAG
    AND Base.LINE = MaxVariableForCDE.LINE
```